# Plotting the sum of values in one column depending on date data in another

Tags: r, date

I am trying to plot sales data. I one column I have dates in following format:

```
"Jul 5, 2013 8:51:00 PM"  
"Jul 14, 2013 11:49:06 PM"
```

etc

I can have multiple transactions each day, so first I convert this string data into date to get rid of time data:

```
sales$Purchased.On <- as.Date(sales$Purchased.On, "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

What I want to have as a result is a dataframe with a date and sales amount column. I can do it with cycle, but I believe there is a solution that more fits R language.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a basic `aggregate` task, e.g.:

```
sales <- data.frame(
 Purchased.On = c("Jul 5, 2013 8:51:00 PM","Jul 14, 2013 11:49:06 PM","Jul 5, 2013 8:51:00 PM","Jul 14, 2013 11:49:06 PM"),
 dollarbillyall=1:4 
)
```

Do your date conversion:

```
sales$Purchased.On <- as.Date(sales$Purchased.On, "%b %d, %Y %H:%M:%S")
```

Resulting in:

```
  Purchased.On dollarbillyall
1   2013-07-05              1
2   2013-07-14              2
3   2013-07-05              3
4   2013-07-14              4
```

Aggregate the data to sum by each date:

```
aggregate(dollarbillyall ~ Purchased.On , data=sales, sum)

#  Purchased.On dollarbillyall
#1   2013-07-05              4
#2   2013-07-14              6
```